# Order of when a variable is set or overriden

Tags: vimrc

In some trial-and-error testing using the following two statements:

```
iabbrev <buffer> return NONONON
autocmd FileType python :iabbrev <buffer> return YESYESYES
```

It looks like regardless of specificity, the `vimrc` will always use the first item encountered. That is, when I open a python file and type in `return`, it will give me `NONONON`. is this a correct understanding? Are there ever any times when a later or more specific item is used, or is it always the first-encountered value used for all commands and such? Where could I find more information on the 'order of how variables are set in the vimrc and such' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't directly define buffer restricted mappings, abbreviations, commands, variables... in the .vimrc. They'll only apply to the first buffer: the one which is active when the `.vimrc` is loaded.

Filetype/syntax related events are triggered after the startup routine described in [`:h startup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#startup)

Comment: thanks -- when would someone want to use the `<buffer>` restriction then? I've been following along to Vimscript the hard way and almost all mapping examples use that.

Comment: In ftplugins, or in _[local vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc)_. I'd recommend to avoid using autocommands for defining ft-specific things: they don't scale well IMO, prefer ftplugins instead.

Comment: thank you. Is the second command I've listed in my question an example of an `ftplugin` or does it literally have to be a file in that folder?

Comment: ftplugins are files. Vim already has `FileType` autocommands that automatically load these files.